# Is there a way to automate Excel Report along with parameters?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, tableau-api

I was wondering if there is a way to automate Excel report along with filters/parameters in specific folder where Users can go and grab the report instead of hitting the server. I know publishing reports in SSRS and Tableau but this has to be moved to certain folder.
        I have seen the subscription option in SSRS (have not worked on subscription part)where reports will be placed in specific folder. But does this option allow users to have filters/parameters selected in the same report? 
    I want the report which has filters where users can select date,employee name etc and then get the result based on the filter in the same report. 
    Is there any other way we can do is>?

Comment: How does the excel file get populated with data?

Comment: I can create a SSRS and also Tableau Report with Parameters. End User doesnt want to hit the SSRS or Tableau server to pull the report though I am insisting that part. So I want to put that report in specific folder along with Parameters so that end user can select filter and view the report.

Comment: With SSRS you can use a data-driven subscription to create the Excel files with different names and parameters for each person.

Comment: thanks @StevenWhite . I will try data-driven subscription.